# onclick submit button anchor to div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, anchor

I have 1 input `type="submit"`, when I click it I would like to open a div and anchor myself to it.

I've tried this, but not work.

```
<form method='post'>
   <input type='submit' onclick='anchor_it();' value='Segnala' name='segnala' style='border:0; background: transparent; margin: 0; cursor: pointer;'>
</form>
<script>
function anchor_it(){
    document.location.href = '#segnala';
}
</script>
<?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){
   echo "<div name='segnala'>xxx</div>";
}
?>
```

If I click, my URL becomes [www.mysite.com/page.php#segnala](http://www.mysite.com/page.php#segnala), but not anchor me to div name `segnala`.

EDIT:
I have solved.

I've solved.

```
<a href='#segnala' onclick='redirect();' style='border:0; background: transparent; margin: 0;'>Segnala</a>
<script>
function redirect(){
    $("#segnala").show();
}
</script>
<div align="center" id="segnala" style="display: none;">
<br>
    prova
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `id='segnala'` instead of `name='segnala'`? (And is the page actually reloading such that the div is written to the page?)

Comment: whit id works, but not work on IE.

Comment: Well it can't help that you have a submit button that would naturally reload the page by submitting the form but you're also changing the `location.href` on click of the same button. Why don't you just set the URL that you want as the form's `action` and remove the JS?

Comment: Any solutions for open a div when click a link?

Comment: Do you actually need to submit anything to the PHP? Where does the div's content come from? It's not clear why you have a form and a submit button if you're just trying to display a div already on the page.

Comment: I could try <a href="#segnala" onclick="$('#segnala').show();">Segnala</a>

Comment: Segnala in Italian means Report. if i click the report button, i would like open a new div, containing a form for report the page.

Answer (score 0):

can you try :

```
<form method='post' action='?archor_it'>
   <input type='submit' onclick='anchor_it();return false;' value='Segnala' name='segnala' style='border:0; background: transparent; margin: 0; cursor: pointer;'>
</form>

<script>
function anchor_it(){
    document.location.href = '#segnala';
}
<?php if(isset($_GET['archor_it'])): ?>
anchor_it();
<?php unset($_GET['archor_it']); endif; ?>
</script>

<?
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST"){
   echo "<div name='segnala'>xxx</div>";
}
?>
```